# Essential appositives

Tags: relative-clauses

Can I use a relative clause ("that is lying on the table") in between a noun phrase ("The book") and its essential appositive ("an English dictionary") as in:

> ```
> The book that is lying on the table an English dictionary has 300 pages.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would use parenthetical commas thus: The book that is lying on the table, an English dictionary, has 300 pages.

Comment: That looks natural to me indeed but as I  understand it, the parenethetical commas would render the appositive a non-essential one and I need to know whether I can use the relative clause with essential appositives.

Comment: @user3100031 Then say: *The English dictionary that is lying on the table has 300 pages.*

Comment: "The English dictionary that is lying on the table has 300 pages." That sentence does not even contain apposition.  That said, a good rewrite is: "The English dictionary on the table has 300 pages." The rest is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

sample sentence:
The book that is lying on the table an English dictionary has 300 pages.

There is no apposition in that sentence.

Now here there is:

**The book, an English dictionary**, lying on the table has 300 pages.

The book is an English dictionary.

**Mr. Smith, the Mayor of Chicago**, was sent to jail.

"Mr. Smith' is in apposition to "the Mayor of Chicago".

[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)

Comment: No. It's ungrammatical, but it is still an *essential* appositive. It's essential if you don't use commas. It's unessential if you do. See [Purdue](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/596/01/). In *your friend* ***Bill*** *is in trouble*, **Bill** is an essential appositive. In *your friend,* ***Bill***, *is in trouble*, **Bill** is an unessential appositive.

Comment: There is no apposition in the non-sentence at all. I did not address the essential bit because first there needs to be apposition. I guess you are OK with this as given in the other sentence?? The book that is lying on the table, an English dictionary, has 300 pages. I can see it is not grammatical.